# Rails postgres query - Model.where(model.has_many_relationship_item.count >= 2)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, relational-database

I need to return an array of a category where a particular item of which it `has_many`, has a `.count >= 2`

I know this sytax is wrong, but I'm trying to figure out the correct way, any tips??

`Model.where(model.has_many_relationship_item.count >= 2) ??`

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category.joins(:items).group("cateogry.id").having("COUNT(items.id) >= 2")

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this is:

```
Model.joins(:items).group('models.id').having('count(items.id) >= 2')
```

assuming (for example) the class of the related model is `Item`

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.joins(:association).group('model_table.id').having('COUNT(association_table.id) >= 2')
```